# Check if an excel sheet is protected and find the password (using apache poi)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, encode

I need to do the following:

User downloads excel file (which is a template) with some columns read only and other editable;(read only columns were made by protecting entire sheet

```
//protect entire sheet
sheet.protectSheet("password");
//create style for editable cells
XSSFCellStyle editableStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
editableStyle.setLocked(false);
//for editable cells apply this style
cell.setCellStyle(editableStyle);
```

User modifies the template file, filling only editable cells

User upload the template

During uploading the template I need to check if the uploaded file is the one downloaded before, protected with exactly the same "password".

I have the possibility to get the password but it is encoded and I don't know how to decode it.

```
byte[] password = sheet.getCTWorksheet().getSheetProtection().getPassword();
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: well, that why they call it protected. and, of course, the password is encrypted and it pretty hard to decode. if not then using password is useless.

Comment: what I really need is to be sure the user uploads into the system the file which was first downloaded. The user doesn't know the password. I am the only one who knows the password using it to protect the sheet in the downloading moment, and then in the uploading moment I want to use the known password to check if the file is the one who was downloaded and not other

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if the file is have the same password, then you can use `validateSheetPassword` method to check it.

Example:

```
if (sheet.validateSheetPassword("password"))
    print("It same password");
```

Or you can see the documentation here: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#validateSheetPassword(java.lang.String)